# Randomize div Positioning.(Leaving a Part of the section)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a testimonials section where I have around 7 images (in this example red divs) in a div placed randomly below it I have a div which displays reviews from the people in the image.

I tried achieving the layout but it is purely static. I want those images to dynamically be placed in the section, except on or below the testimonials div(in this case blue div.

I want the placement and positioning of divs to be dynamic because if I add more than 7 images (in this case divs) I need to write the positioning statically for every image.

**Inspirational image**

[image]

Following is the code I have tried.

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a.img {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
}

.img1 {
  left: -20%;
  top: 75px;
}

.img2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: -5%;
}

.img3 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 5%;
}

.img4 {
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
}

.img5 {
  top: 20px;
  right: 350px;
}

.img6 {
  top: 60px;
  right: 250px;
}

.img7 {
  top: 30px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
    <a href="#" class="img img1" data-id="review1"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img img2" data-id="review2"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img img3" data-id="review3"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img img4" data-id="review4"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img img5" data-id="review5"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img img6" data-id="review6"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img img7" data-id="review7"></a>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To place the images on the red divs you can loop through all your images with the class `.img` using `.each()` and set the images for each element.

I'm assuming that the image names are the `data-id` attribute of all your anchor (`<a>`) tags, thus, you can get the image name by using `.data('id')`. Now that you have the image name you can "build" your DOM element to place on the red box, and then add that to the red box (the anchor tag) using `.html()`.

Please see a working example below (the images in this example won't work as they don't exist yet):

```js
$('.img').each((_, elem) => {
  let img_id = $(elem).data('id');
  let img = `<img style='height: 100%; width: 100%;' src="${img_id}.png" alt='${img_id} image'/>`;
  $(elem).html(img);
});
```

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a.img {
  content: '';
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
}

.img1 {
  left: -20%;
  top: 75px;
}

.img2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: -5%;
}

.img3 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 5%;
}

.img4 {
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
}

.img5 {
  top: 20px;
  right: 350px;
}

.img6 {
  top: 60px;
  right: 250px;
}

.img7 {
  top: 30px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <a href="#" class="img img1" data-id="review1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="img img2" data-id="review2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="img img3" data-id="review3"></a>
  <a href="#" class="img img4" data-id="review4"></a>
  <a href="#" class="img img5" data-id="review5"></a>
  <a href="#" class="img img6" data-id="review6"></a>
  <a href="#" class="img img7" data-id="review7"></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, the question was not concerned to images the question was about the random positioning of the divisions. I apologize if I made you misunderstand the question.